# Connect to MSSQL using php from Mac OS X, "No data received"

Tags: php, sql-server, macos, mamp, freetds

I needed to be able to connect to the mssql server at work on my laptop. I followed this tutorial to help me connect : http://lkrms.org/php-with-freetds-on-os-x-mavericks/

When I run the phpinfo(), I see that mssql is perfectly loaded, when I try to connect using the mssql_connect function, I get a "No data received" with this error :

Unable to load the webpage because the server sent no data. Error code: ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

I checked the php log, there is absolutely nothing.

I'm using MAMP on Mac OS X Mavericks. I'm 100% sure that I'm using the right server address, port, user, password, everything.

EDIT: I get those errors in my apache log:

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _iconv_open
Referenced from: /usr/local/freetds/lib/libsybdb.5.dylib
Expected in: /Applications/MAMP/Library/lib/libiconv.2.dylib

dyld: Symbol not found: _iconv_open
Referenced from: /usr/local/freetds/lib/libsybdb.5.dylib
Expected in: /Applications/MAMP/Library/lib/libiconv.2.dylib

dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _iconv_open
Referenced from: /usr/local/freetds/lib/libsybdb.5.dylib
Expected in: /Applications/MAMP/Library/lib/libiconv.2.dylib

dyld: Symbol not found: _iconv_open
Referenced from: /usr/local/freetds/lib/libsybdb.5.dylib
Expected in: /Applications/MAMP/Library/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
```

Answer (score 1):

I recently ran into a similar issue.
MAMP tries to append it's own paths to DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH which was causing some confusion with FreeTDS.

Open MAMP/Library/bin/envars and comment out:

`if test "x$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH" != "x" ; then
  DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="/Applications/MAMP/Library/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH"
 else
  DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="/Applications/MAMP/Library/lib"
 fi
 export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`

Good luck!